# Homestead.yaml routes causing "No input file specified"

Tags: laravel, unix, vagrant, homestead

I am having problem with the correct routes for my Homestead.yaml file and is currently displaying the following "No input file specified."

The code is as follows:

```
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/web/sites
      to: /home/vagrant/web/sites

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/web/sites/test

databases:
    - homestead
```

How would I correct my problems?

**UPDATE**

```
    provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/web/
      to: /home/vagrant/web

sites:
    - map: PGM.app
      to: /home/vagrant/web/PGM/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sites need to have an index file. For example, if you test directory is a Laravel or Lumen application, it has a public directory

```
sites:
  - map: test.app
    to: /home/vagrant/web/sites/test/public
```

Note the addition of public on the end of the path.

Once you've made changes to your Homestead.yml file, you'll need to re-provision the VM using the following to apply the changes.

```
homestead provision
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Swimburne, I am still having problem I have updated the code that I am using above. Can you see anything?

Comment: I also used vagrant provision as homestead provision didnt work

Comment: @JamesParsons Perhaps ssh onto the machine and ensure that the directories have mapped correctly. Also try adding `type: "nfs"` to the `folders: map: ... to: ... type: "nfs"`

Comment: @JamesParsons any luck?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Ben Swinburne all has been sorted, thanks for you help.